# Connecting 3.3 and 5 V devices

Tags: voltage-divider, logic-level

The requirements are different from similar questions I've found here.
TXB/TXS are expensive for my needs. 
Sparkfun's logic shifter is bi-directional, while I need two uni-directional conversions,  `RX<->TX` pairs.

As far as I understood from datasheets of both devices, the logic levels
ATMega328P (VCC=5V) [page 313](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf)

\$V_{l}\$ = 0v - 0.3v
\$V_{h}\$ = 0.6v - 5v

and GPS receiver's [page 16](http://docs.mirifica.it/GTop-tech.com/MediaTek_MT3339/FGPMMOPA6C_PA6C/documents/GlobalTop-FGPMMOPA6C-Datasheet-V0A-Preliminary.pdf)

\$V_{l}\$ = 0v - 0.8v
\$V_{h}\$ = 2v - 3.3v

I've tried to do that with voltage divider, but doesn't look like it's possible or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Looking for something like this: http://husstechlabs.com/support/tutorials/bi-directional-level-shifter/

Comment: @sandund hammika I was hoping for uni-directional solution, especially 3.3 -> 5 direction, with hope of cost effective solution for just 1 signal conversion. Again, I don't have "line sharing" situation.

Comment: Is running the ATMega328P at 3V3 an option? `ATmega48P/88P/168P: 0 - 10 MHz @ 2.7 - 5.5V, 0 - 20 MHz @ 4.5 - 5.5V`

Comment: @jippie: interesting approach. But then I have MAX7219, some other IC's... but I'll think about it. Not sure how it will affect FTDI if I run ATMega from 3v3. +1

Comment: You have your V(HI) for the AT wrong. It is 0.6 × Vcc.

Comment: Yep, I missed the xVCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong figures. You must use the output figures for the output, and the input figures for the input, and do that in both directions and for 0 and 1.

For the AT->GPS:

- AT out maximum for 0: 0.9 V
- GPS in maximum for 0: 0.8 V

Strictly speaking the AT might not pull the line low enough, but in practice (with no load on the line) this will be OK, even without a voltage divider.

- AT out for 1: min 4V2, can be up to 5V
- GPS in for 1: min 2V0, max Vcc (3V3)

This is a problem. A voltage divider will do fine at this low speed, don't take the values too high. I would take 1k5 / 1k, but probably 10k / 10k will do just as well.

For the GPS ->AT:

- GPS out at 0: 0 .. 0.4
- GPS out at 1 : 2.4 .. 2.8
- AT in at 0: 0 .. 1.5V
- AT in at 1: 3 .. 5.5V

One problem here: the output level of the GPS for a 1 is not enough to be guaranteed to be seen as 1 by the AT. You can go for tricky passive solutions here, but a simple HCT gate at 5V will do the trick, their minumum input level for 1 is 2V0. Take for instance a 74HCT00 (2 gates in series), or any other non-inverting set of gates.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer. The baudrate between AT -> GPS may be as high as 115000 bps. Should it be still fine to use voltage divider? As for GPS -> AT, can I use transistor along with Schottky? If using 74HCT00, VCC is 5v or 3v3?

Comment: I think a 1k5/1k divider will work at 115200, but I am not sure. Try it. If let's say 3k3/2k7 seems to work, switch to 1k5/1k and sleep well because you have some margin. Transistor with sckottky: not enough data, specify the exact circuit. I don't immediately see how to make a non-inverting level shifter with 1 transistor (unless it is the I2C trick, which requires a mosfet).

Comment: How about 74HCT00 VCC? Also should I connect gate's A/B pins together and connect it directly to GPS TX? Then Y goes directly to AT RX pin? As for transistor, disregard it, thought there is some common solution with bipolar transistor.

Comment: Don't completely disregard transistor, because I've found this: http://i.imgur.com/jKV1g.png

Comment: That is 2 transistors. Nothing wrong with that, but a lot more complex (and expensive) than a HCT chip. Yes, the HCT would be powered by 5V, as I mentioned. Note that you don't want inversion, so you must use two gates of a 74HCT00 chip. or use any other non-inverting gate combination.

Answer (score 1):

For 5V -> 3V3 use a simple resistor divider or a transistor. For 3V3 -> 5V use a simple transistor: just drive its base using 3V3 signal.

Comment: Resistive divider 6.8k and 13k. For logical 0 0-0.3v it will work. For logical 1, which is 0.6-5v probably not, because out of 0.6 I can't get 2v. Please check the values in my original post. Scaling doesn't work, unless I misinterpreting datasheets.

Answer (score 1):

This is how V-USB project does it for communication between a 5V AT(mega|tiny) and 3.6V USB. The trick here is in what the AT sees as a HIGH (0.6 × Vcc). So if your GPS module will output a HIGH as 3.0V then it should work just fine with the zener setup. Maybe if you carefully design the wires between GPS and AT, the 3V output for GPS won't be a problem.

Notice that your project uses 3.3V, whereas USB data lines are at 3.6V.

[image]

Comment: GPS out is from 2.4 - 2.8

Comment: In your question is `Vh = 2v - 3.3v`

Comment: That's input in my question. Plz refer to datasheet.

Comment: That's too bad. I'll delete my answer if I get +3 votes on it, so at least I get a 'Disciplined'-badge for my efforts ;o)

Comment: that was my fault not to be clear, but it's lack of experience )